# How to make TextView float vertically in the centre relative to an ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make the TextView containing the text "This is some long text" to float in the centre relative to the image on the left, but mine currently looks like:

[image]

This TextView can take up to 2 lines of text, so if it does have 2 lines, I hope to make it restore to the standard alignment like:

[image]

Here's my layout now:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_left"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/the_pirates"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        />

<TextView android:id="@+id/relationship_caption"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="8dp"
          android:text="This is some long text"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/user_left"
          android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried setting `gravity` to `center`, but that didn't seem to have helped.\

Thanks!

Comment: @ASP setting `gravity` to `center_vertical` doesn't achieve it, as I'm trying to get the text to float center with respect to the image on the left.

Comment: set `centerVertical="true"` in TextView

Comment: try putting your imageview and textview in a horizontal LinearLayout and then work on it.

Comment: @ASP Piyush's solution of setting alignTop. But it seems alignBottom is also needed.

Comment: @ASP That solution doesn't work for me. What I get is an image in the corner, but the next being in the middle of the screen (rather than middle of w.r.t the image).

Comment: did u try android:layout_gravity="left" for your textview.

Comment: @ASP That might mean I'll need to wrap the TextView in another layout, right? That seems a bit complex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_left"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/the_pirates" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/relationship_caption"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/user_left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_left"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="This is some long text"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ya you can see i have also added that one.

Comment: But it seems the 'centering' is purely defined by the margin. Is there a way to just let it be vertically centred w.r.t the top and bottom of the image?

Comment: means exactly centered between image?

Comment: Got it. I've aligned the bottom as well and set `gravity` to `center`. Hopefully it's the proper way of doing things.

Comment: I think it needs both alignBottom and alignTop.

Comment: Yes, I have. For me, that sticks to the bottom. What seems to work for me is to have both alignTop and alignBottom along with gravity to center_vertical.

Comment: Ya you have to apply that one.

Answer (score 0):

here i have done what you want

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" >//here you can give your size

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_left"
            android:layout_width="120dp"//here you can put your size as you want
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/relationship_caption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_left"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="This is some long text"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```